# What are the best free CASE tools for PHP?

Tags: php, code-generation, case, modeling

What are your favorite **free** CASE/UML/Code generation/diagramming tools that you **use with PHP**?

There are various commercial products that support code generation in PHP language, are there any free CASE tools? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 4):

Well first we need to distinguish between Higher and Lower CASE tools.
Higer tools are the ones that help you develop sw through all it's live cycle.
I'm unaware of such a tool for php.

However in the lower CASE side we have [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) from their website:

> The PHP generation is provided with all ArgoUML releases since 0.13.2 (March 2003) in the "modules"-file.

Also you might want to check [DBDesigner](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/), from their site:

> DBDesigner 4 is a visual database design system that integrates database design, modeling, creation and maintenance into a single, seamless environment.

Comment: +1 for mentioning DBDesigner. It is all I need :)